# What is the solution for a tedious Nvidia GTX 960M graphic card?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, laptop, asus

I just I feel scammed when I got a laptop with Nvidia graphics card which preforms poorly with Ubuntu or any other Linux distro. I've tried Fedora, Ubuntu, OpenSuse and many other, thanks to Nvidia their drivers break the system.

I've installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I installed Nvidia GTX 960M driver, from additional drivers utility. Whenever I restart my notebook, as long as I don't change the driver settings to Intel the system works fine. The moment I change the driver to Intel, the system breaks and I had to use recovery mode to remove the Nvidia driver. Swiching to Intel from nvidia-prime causes the fan to rotate fast and I get nothing once I reboot, I just see a black screen with nothing in it.

For Ubuntu 17.04 I can't speak. I feel lucky to be able to install Nvidia driver in Ubuntu 16.04. Under 17.04 once I install the driver, I had to go back to recovery mode and remove the Nvidia driver completely. I had probably installed Ubuntu and other Linux distro multiple times and I just think now about getting rid of my notebook which is Asus GL-752VW for the sake of installing Linux. I can't cope with Windows by nature.

I also tried to install Nvidia driver from nvidia.com, it didn't work.

For the moment, I don't care if Nvidia graphic card will run on my machine, I just need to make the Intel graphic card work and let Nvidia card to shut the f*** up. When I tried to just use Intel, Ubuntu will not boot or shutdown properly, because it tries to detect GPUs which takes forever, so I have to press the shutdown button each to force the shutdown. How can I use Intel graphic card alone? I just don't need to use Nvidia with Linux and I'll never buy anything from this company ever again.

Comment: Did you try to use the command: nvidia-select intel   to switch?

Comment: I don't know why the question is marked as duplicate! That question doesn't not reflect anything that I'm talking about in this question. I'm not asking how to switch between Intel or Nvidia! I have a buggy driver issue from the sick Nvidia.

Comment: @direpobs And, what is it a duplicate of?

Comment: @RaffiKhatchadourian I've actually solved the problem with a kernel parameter.

Comment: @direprobs Could you elaborate? My machine crashes multiple times on a daily basis :(.

Comment: @RaffiKhatchadourian I'm not aware of what kind of machine you have. Mine is ASUS ROG GL752. However, you can try these kernel parameters: for `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAUL`T add `acpi_osi=!` and `acpi_osi=\"Windows 2009\"` and then run `update-grub`. I'm assuming you're using grub.

Comment: @direprobs I'm using an Alienware Aurora R6 and yes using grub.

Comment: @RaffiKhatchadourian  If somehow things didn't work out as they're supposed to, contact Nvidia that's the only genuine solution you can get, the driver that I use on my machine is proprietary so nobody could help other than Nvidia or consider using Nouvea driver which is an open source alternative.

Comment: @direprobs I think that the windows 2009 flag helped with the crashes but I have to say that the graphics seem to still be very sluggish.

Comment: @RaffiKhatchadourian In comparison with Windows, yes.

Comment: Ah never mind. Started crashing again.

Comment: Even in comparison to my laptop running the same version of Ubuntu but a different video card it's sluggish.

Comment: @RaffiKhatchadourian I'm quite sure if you post the details of your problem in [Nvidia devtalk forum](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/) they'll be able to assist you. That's how I got my problem solved essentially.